# How to uninstall DWService?

Tags: software-uninstall

Home due to COVID.  I looked at [DWService](https://github.com/dwservice/agent) and installed it.

Found that it slowed down anything I was typing or sending.

How do I uninstall DWService on my desktop?

[image]

Comment: well the obvious question you will get is: how did you install it?

Comment: @User24601 The above duplicate link doesn't provide any answers to this question.